# Updating a View column using a single form field

Tags: forms, view

Appreciate any helpful answers to this query.

I have an Apex App (4.x) where I have a view:  `PRICE_MODEL_CRA_V`

In the view, I have the following applicable columns:

```
COUNTRY
GRADE
SALARY
```

In the form I have the following fields

```
:P16_COUNTRY (DROPDOWN)
:P16_GRADE (DROPDOWN)
:P16_SALARY (Number)
```

In my app, I have a form with an Update button.  I am simply trying to get Apex to update all rows in the salaray column in the view, where the country and grade match.

I've the following code for the Update button:

```
UPDATE PRICE_MODEL_CRA_V
SET SALARY = :P16_SALARY
WHERE COUNTRY = :P16_COUNTRY
AND GRADE = :P16_GRADE
```

The option I have chosen in condition type is:

Value of Item  / Column expression is NOT Null (as there are values in the column)

Also tried SQL Expression and it does not like..says that there is No Expression.

Thanks again if anyone can help :)